# Django error while using month filter

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am following the django tutorial and was able to run the __year filter but when I try to use the month filter I get the error. Following is the commands that I have tried after starting python manage.py shell

```
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> current_year = timezone.now().year
>>> current_month = timezone.now().month
>>> print (current_year)
2014
>>> print (current_month)
9
>>> Choice.objects.filter(question__pub_date__year=current_year)
[<Choice: Not much>, <Choice: the sky>, <Choice: Just hacking again>]
>>> Choice.objects.filter(question__pub_date__month=current_month)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 116, in _
_repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 141, in _
_iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 966, in _
fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 265, in i
terator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 70
0, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 77
5, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 10
9, in as_sql
    where, w_params = self.compile(self.query.where)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 80
, in compile
    return node.as_sql(self, self.connection)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\where.py", line 106,
in as_sql
    sql, params = qn.compile(child)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 80
, in compile
    return node.as_sql(self, self.connection)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 149, in
 as_sql
    lhs_sql, params = self.process_lhs(qn, connection)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 304, in
 process_lhs
    sql, tz_params = connection.ops.datetime_extract_sql(self.extract_type, lhs,
 tzname)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line
197, in datetime_extract_sql
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("This query requires pytz, "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: This query requires pytz, but it is
n't installed.
```

I am using windows 7 64 bit operating system
Python 3.4.1
Django 1.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/timezones/), if you have timezone support enables

`settings.py`
`USE_TZ = True`

then you need to install the `pytz` module

`pip install pytz`

and this is also showing in the last line of your error.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I was able to get to work after installing pytz.Any idea why year worked without it and month required pytz for wokring ?